# What is the efficient way to pick X from a list of Y with Z quantities in stock?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have been trying to find a way to create an efficient way of selecting a combination of packs based on the pack size and the amount of packs available.

For example a customer orders 370 widgets.

The supplier sells widgets in packs of 10, 30 and 50.

I know to meet the order efficiently I would need 7x of 50 pack and 2x of 10 pack.

But what if the supplier only had the following quantities of packs in their warehouse?

- 100x of 10 pack
- 30x of 30 pack
- 5x of 50 pack

The most efficient for my purposes should be 5x of 50 pack and 4x of 30 pack.

How could I automate this type of order picking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to try Solver add-in. It uses linear and non-linear calculation algorithms to solve equations. It is a built-in add-in and you can activate it from **File > Options > Add-Ins > Select *Excel Add-ins* > Click Go**.

[image: screenshot shows formulas and Solver settings]

For more detailed information search for *linear programming*.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to linear programming! It was very helpful as I was not sure where to start. It's not as efficient as I would like but it does the job and I'm happy with it. I did have to modify the constraints as per the following image [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/MDtTsr8.jpg)

Comment: @angelofdev I thought you may need to prioritize your variables; so I updated my model a bit. I added weights to it and updated my goal to maximize the total weighted quantity. Also; I should have added **customer order = total qty** equation as a _constraint_. Here is a screenshot [Imgur](https://imgur.com/a/8hbJ9fE)